# Adding if-else Logic to My Applescript (depending on whether a FIND gets a match)

Tags: applescript

I've got an applescript that does lots of text manipulation, then searches for a text string, selects that text string,  runs a python script on the selection, inserts the output, and selects and copies that output. Then the applescript procedes with more actions.

Problem: the text string searched for and operated on by that Python script isn't always present. If not, I'd want it to jump past the python part and resume the rest of my applescript.

Here's the salient part of the script, below. I'll start out with the final action of my AppleScript before the Python script cuts in:

```
replace "Claimed" using "" searching in text 1 of text document 1 options {starting at top:true, case sensitive:true}

#here is where my script searches for the text string  the Python script will operate on (and which may NOT be present):

find "^Mon .+" searching in text 1 of text document 1 options {search mode:grep, wrap around:true, case sensitive:true} with selecting match

#here's the python part (which shouldn't be triggered if the string, above, isn't found):

set unprocessed to contents of selection

set processed to (do shell script ("python ~/Library/Scripts/yelpmanip.py '" & unprocessed & "'"))

set contents of selection to processed

copy selection

#If python script didn't run, I'd want to resume below:

find "events" searching in text 1 of text document 1 options {search mode:grep, wrap around:true} with selecting match

tell application "System Events" to key code 126 using {shift down, command down}
#etc etc
end tell
```

Comment: I'm attempting to answer this question, but I can't find documentation for the `replace` routine. Do you know where this documentation is?

Comment: Also, I think this question is not really about a Python script. The question is how to check if the `find` command found a match, and then just use if-else logic to decide what to do from there. So, I would change the title of your post.

Comment: Elliott, I derived that code by having Applescript follow my actions in BBedit as I did a search/replace. This is how it captured the action, and it seems to work well. I'll try to improve the title, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use `set match to find ...` to grab the result, and check using the syntax `if found of match`.

Source: https://nathangrigg.com/2012/06/bbedit-search-with-applescript.

Code (not tested):

```
replace "Claimed" using "" searching in text 1 of text document 1 options {starting at top:true, case sensitive:true}

#here is where my script searches for the text string  the Python script will operate on (and which may NOT be present):

set match to find "^Mon .+" searching in text 1 of text document 1 options {search mode:grep, wrap around:true, case sensitive:true} with selecting match

#here's the python part (which shouldn't be triggered if the string, above, isn't found):

if found of match then

    set unprocessed to contents of selection

    set processed to (do shell script ("python ~/Library/Scripts/yelpmanip.py '" & unprocessed & "'"))

    set contents of selection to processed

    copy selection

end if

#If python script didn't run, I'd want to resume below:

find "events" searching in text 1 of text document 1 options {search mode:grep, wrap around:true} with selecting match

tell application "System Events" to key code 126 using {shift down, command down}
#etc etc
end tell
```

Comment: You can accept my answer. Do you know how to do that? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers